# Harmonic sum of sequence of real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

if $\left \{ x_n \right \}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that

\begin{equation}
x_1=2 \tag{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x_{n+1}=x_n^2-x_n+1, \,\,\forall n=1,2,3\cdots\ \tag{2}
\end{equation}

if $$k=\sum_{i=1}^{1000}\frac{1}{x_i}$$ Then which of the following is/are true:

$1.$ $k \lt 0.5$

$2.$ $k \lt 1$

$3.$ $k \gt 1$

$4.$ $k \lt \frac{5}{6} $

Answer (score 3):

My Try: Since $$x_n^2-x_n+1 \gt 0$$ $\forall x_n\in \mathbb{R}$ The sequence is positive real sequence.

Now $$x_{n+1}=(x_n-1)^2+(x_n-1)+1$$ $\implies$

$$x_{n+1}-1=(x_n-1)^2+(x_n-1)$$ Let $y_n=x_n-1$, So $y_1=1$ and

$$y_{n+1}=y_n(y_n+1)$$ $\implies$

$$\frac{1}{y_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{y_n}-\frac{1}{y_n+1}=\frac{1}{y_n}-\frac{1}{x_n}$$ $\implies$

$$\frac{1}{x_n}=\frac{1}{y_n}-\frac{1}{y_{n+1}}$$

So $$\sum_{i=1}^{999}\frac{1}{x_i}=\frac{1}{y_1}-\frac{1}{y_{1000}}=1-\frac{1}{x_{1000}-1}$$ So

$$k=\sum_{i=1}^{1000}\frac{1}{x_i}=1-\frac{1}{\left(x_{1000}\left(x_{1000}-1\right)\right)}$$ Since $$x_{1000} \gg 1$$ Conclusion is $$k \lt 1$$

Please let me know if there any other approach...

Comment: This method looks awesome to me! +1